# Pulling data from Microsoft Access Snapshot(.snp) files

Tags: ms-access

Is there any method to extract the data from a snapshot file?

Comment: Any reason you cannot obtain a copy of the mdb/accdb?

Comment: Sorry I got lost at school and work : ).  Yeah mso we work for only provides us with the snapshot.  I've ask for the data in a cvs or excel format, but that doesn't seem like it's gonna happen.

Answer (score 0):

A simple but crude way would be to print the snap file using the XPS document writer, open the resulting file in internet explorer, copy the required data and then paste it into excel.

Or were you after a more automated solution?

Comment: I was looking for a more automated solution, but I will try what you suggested and use that method until something better presents itself.

Thanks